# In Excel how do I convert a location's address to a block address for privacy without redacting intersections or location names?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to convert:

`11448 12TH AVE SW` to `11400 BLOCK 12TH AVE SW`

or

`17870 13TH AVE N` to `17800 BLOCK 13TH AVE N.`

I would like intersections not to be redacted.

Example using my own personal data from King County Sheriff's Office public records request:

```
    Address
12 AV SW / SW 118 ST
11448 12 AVE SW, BUR 
11448 12TH AVE SW,KCS 
11448 12TH AVE SW,KCS 
SW 116TH ST / 12TH AVE SW,KCS 
11448 12TH AVE SW,BUR 
BREWSKY'S BAR AND GRILL,KCS 
11448 12TH AVE SW,BUR 
AMBAUM BLVD SW / SW 122ND ST,BUR 
11448 12TH AVE SW,BUR 
BURIEN TC,BUR 
11448 12TH AVE SW,BUR 
11448 12TH AVE SW,BUR 
11439 12TH AVE SW,BUR
9811 15TH AVE SW,KCS 
SW 116TH ST / 16TH AVE SW,BUR 
11448 12TH AVE SW,BUR 
11038 4TH AVE SW, KCS
SW 116TH ST/12TH AVE SW, BUR 
1524 3RD AVE, SEA
SW 100TH ST/15TH AVE SW, KCS
11448 12TH AVE SW, BUR 
BURIEN EVANGELICAL CHURCH
11448 12TH AVE SW, BUR 
PIKE ST/3RD AVE, SEA 
MOTEL 6 - L3, STC 
11448 12TH AVE SW, BUR 
3000 S 176TH ST, STC 
SW ROXBURY ST/28TH AVE SW, KCS
SW ROXBURY ST/28TH AVE SW, KCS 
SAFEWAY - N5, BUR
SW TRENTON ST/25TH AVE SW, SEA 
11448 12TH AVE SW, BUR 
KING CO COURTHOUSE, SEA 
11448 12TH AVE SW, BUR 
11448 12TH AVE SW, BUR
```

Comment: I've never used Excel before.

Comment: I googled before writing this question and couldn't find anything.

Comment: I can help with this.... give me a few minutes.

Comment: I sure hope all this information you just posted online in a public forum is mock data

Comment: It's my personal data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help you better understand these formulas, I'm first splitting them up. Then, at the end you can combine them altogether as one if you prefer.

**Formula 1** (get the street address before the first space):

```
=LEFT(A2,(FIND(" ",A2,1)-1))
```

**Formula 2** (get the remaining address after the first space):

```
=MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2),200)
```

**Formula 3**: Round the street and concatenate your results:

```
=CONCAT(FLOOR(B2,100)," BLOCK",C2)
```

**Combine as one long formula:**

```
=CONCAT(FLOOR(LEFT(A2,(FIND(" ",A2,1)-1)),100)," BLOCK",MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2),200))
```

This is rounding the address down to the 100 number, and, limiting the remaining address to 200 characters. Adjust as needed. In my opinion, this doesn't offer much privacy as some blocks may have just one house. Also, if the street has an address less than 100, then you may need to add an "if" statement and adjust the formula.

[image]

**UPDATED...**

Updates based on new data you provided. Assuming that an intersection always has a forward slash (/), and, assuming you don't want to change if the address does not start with a number, then this will work...

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("/",A2)),ISERR(VALUE(LEFT(A2,1)))),A2,CONCAT(FLOOR(LEFT(A2,(FIND(" ",A2,1)-1)),100)," BLOCK",MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2),200)))
```

The address will not change if it contains a forward slash OR if it starts with a letter. Otherwise, the address will change by the rules defined before.

[image]

Comment: I didn't think of intersections, can they be identified and left unredacted? I added examples.

Comment: @TimClemans The data looks like one big blob to me. I cannot read it. Also, this looks like sensitive info. Beware.

Comment: It's my own personal data and I already posted it publicly on my site. I fixed the formatting.

Comment: @TimClemans I would just include the address data that you're inquiring about. This is too much to look at and cannot be copied/pasted into excel because there's no delimiter. Remove all columns but the one you are concerned about.

Comment: fixed it so it's just the address column

Comment: @TimClemans Just updated.